# Inter-process communication between docker container and its host

Tags: docker, ipc

I am setting up a continuous integration system with gtilab and docker. For some reason I have to commit the current container as a new docker image in one stage of the CI system, so I can reuse the image in subsequent stages.

To summarize, I have to execute this command:

```
docker commit $CONTAINER_ID $NEW_IMAGE_NAME
```

But from inside a container. And later from another container:

```
docker rmi $NEW_IMAGE_NAME
```

One solution might be setting up ssh public key authentication and:

```
ssh user@172.17.0.1 docker ...
```

In which, 172.17.0.1 is the host IP address. I can restrict the ssh user to access only specific commands for security.

Another solution is to create a public service on a network socket in the host. But what is the best approach here? I prefer a secure solution so from inside the container you can only commit a docker image and delete the created image (and not other images). So, a wild ssh is not so secure. And, I prefer a more portable solution that doesn't relay on the host IP address. What do you suggest?

Comment: Could you explicit the communication need. How could you write the protocol specification or the API the containers would need please?

Comment: I only need to execute two simple commands from inside the container: docker commit and docker rmi, but with the restriction that rmi could only remove the previous user's committed image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue/Question

How to execute some Docker API call from within a container?

#### Did you know

Did you know that the Docker API can be served on a networking socket by adding the option `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`? Hence you can execute calls from within the containers directly to the Docker daemon.

Note that you can (and should) also enable TLS for this socket, cf `man docker daemon`.

#### Security is a must

If ever this option does not seem clean or secure enough, then a local networking* service will be needed. I would suggest a web API in `java` or `python` that would respond to two different call that could be:

1. **commit**: `http[s]://localhost:service-port/commit?containder_id=123456789&image_name=my_name`
2. **rmi**: `http[s]://localhost:service-port/rmi?containder_id=123456789`

*I did not understand in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998845/inter-process-communication-between-docker-container-and-its-host#comment61552127_36998845) what **user** you refer to.*

The local service would then answer a `HTTP 201 Created` if the image is created, or `HTTP 406 Not Acceptable` if the name already exists. It could also checks if no more than one `rmi` in a raw are performed. It could answer a `HTTP 204 Not Content` if no image with this ID exists, `HTTP 403 Forbidden` is the image cannot be deleted or `HTTP 200 OK` if everything went well. In a last resort it could answer `HTTP 418 I'm a teapot`.

---

*: local-networking is a fast, mostly secure, easy to deploy and natively works with Docker. FIFO, see `man mkfifo`, could also be used but would require another shared volume (for the FIFO file) and, maybe, more code.

Comment: Local networking seems reasonable. I didn't know about -H and docker API on the network but I can't use it directly for the security matter. The word user in my comment refers to the gitlab which is the user inside the container that should commit and rmi the image.